# Symfony 2 Doctrine:Fixtures:Load Undefined Index

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I have been using Symfony2 lately, and I've been following this tutorial: [tutorial.co.symblog.co.uk](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk)

Unfortunately, since the tutorial was written a long time ago, many things are wrong. I've been able to fix most of them through the employment of common sense, but this one is tricky...

I'm creating a blog, and have Data Fixtures for Blog Posts, and Comments on those Blog Posts. When I run:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures load
```

I get:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: blog-1 in /private_html/symfony/symblog/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/ReferenceRepository.php on line 154
```

Here are my blog fixtures:

```
<?php
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/BlogFixtures.php

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog;

class BlogFixtures implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $blog1 = new Blog();
        $blog1->setTitle('A day with Symfony2');
        $blog1->setBlog('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eletra electrify denim vel ports.\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ut velocity magna. Etiam vehicula nunc non leo hendrerit commodo. Vestibulum vulputate mauris eget erat congue dapibus imperdiet justo scelerisque. Nulla consectetur tempus nisl vitae viverra. Cras el mauris eget erat congue dapibus imperdiet justo scelerisque. Nulla consectetur tempus nisl vitae viverra. Cras elementum molestie vestibulum. Morbi id quam nisl. Praesent hendrerit, orci sed elementum lobortis, justo mauris lacinia libero, non facilisis purus ipsum non mi. Aliquam sollicitudin, augue id vestibulum iaculis, sem lectus convallis nunc, vel scelerisque lorem tortor ac nunc. Donec pharetra eleifend enim vel porta.');
        $blog1->setImage('beach.jpg');
        $blog1->setAuthor('Parth Sarin');
        $blog1->setTags('symfony2, php, paradise, symblog');
        $blog1->setCreated(new \DateTime());
        $blog1->setUpdated($blog1->getCreated());
        $manager->persist($blog1);

        $blog2 = new Blog();
        $blog2->setTitle('The pool on the roof must have a leak');
        $blog2->setBlog('Vestibulum vulputate mauris eget erat congue dapibus imperdiet justo scelerisque. Na. Cras elementum molestie vestibulum. Morbi id quam nisl. Praesent hendrerit, orci sed elementum lobortis.');
        $blog2->setImage('pool_leak.jpg');
        $blog2->setAuthor('Zero Cool');
        $blog2->setTags('pool, leaky, hacked, movie, hacking, symblog');
        $blog2->setCreated(new \DateTime("2011-07-23 06:12:33"));
        $blog2->setUpdated($blog2->getCreated());
        $manager->persist($blog2);

        $blog3 = new Blog();
        $blog3->setTitle('Misdirection. What the eyes see and the ears hear, the mind believes');
        $blog3->setBlog('Lorem ipsumvehicula nunc non leo hendrerit commodo. Vestibulum vulputate mauris eget erat congue dapibus imperdiet justo scelerisque.');
        $blog3->setImage('misdirection.jpg');
        $blog3->setAuthor('Gabriel');
        $blog3->setTags('misdirection, magic, movie, hacking, symblog');
        $blog3->setCreated(new \DateTime("2011-07-16 16:14:06"));
        $blog3->setUpdated($blog3->getCreated());
        $manager->persist($blog3);

        $blog4 = new Blog();
        $blog4->setTitle('The grid - A digital frontier');
        $blog4->setBlog('Lorem commodo. Vestibulum vulputate mauris eget erat congue dapibus imperdiet justo scelerisque. Nulla consectetur tempus nisl vitae viverra.');
        $blog4->setImage('the_grid.jpg');
        $blog4->setAuthor('Kevin Flynn');
        $blog4->setTags('grid, daftpunk, movie, symblog');
        $blog4->setCreated(new \DateTime("2011-06-02 18:54:12"));
        $blog4->setUpdated($blog4->getCreated());
        $manager->persist($blog4);

        $blog5 = new Blog();
        $blog5->setTitle('You\'re either a one or a zero. Alive or dead');
        $blog5->setBlog('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elittibulum vulputate mauris eget erat congue dapibus imperdiet justo scelerisque.');
        $blog5->setImage('one_or_zero.jpg');
        $blog5->setAuthor('Gary Winston');
        $blog5->setTags('binary, one, zero, alive, dead, !trusting, movie, symblog');
        $blog5->setCreated(new \DateTime("2011-04-25 15:34:18"));
        $blog5->setUpdated($blog5->getCreated());
        $manager->persist($blog5);

        $manager->flush();

        $this->addReference('blog-1', $blog1);
        $this->addReference('blog-2', $blog2);
        $this->addReference('blog-3', $blog3);
        $this->addReference('blog-4', $blog4);
        $this->addReference('blog-5', $blog5);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need anything else, and as always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend `AbstractFixture` in `BlogFixtures` class :

```
class BlogFixtures  extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface{ ... }
```

docs : 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures